# How can I do a conditional collectEntries in groovy

Tags: dictionary, collections, groovy

Is it possible to do a conditional collectEntries like collect ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
[ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 ].findAll { it.value > 2 }
```

should do it

Comment: For me, the whole point of `collectEntries` is generating a new kind of item, different from the source collection's items. Your answer is just filtering out unwanted items.

Comment: Also, `collectEntries` can be applied to any iterable, not just a map. Here's an example: take a source array, filter some items, and transform it into a map, all in one operation:
`println([ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ].collectEntries { it <= 'c' ? [ it, it.toUpperCase() ] : [:] })`. Result: `[a:A, b:B, c:C]`

Comment: P.S. I've checked the original question and it was indeed asking a much more specific question, to which your answer is the most straightforward answer. However, as the question stands now, Nathan Hughes's answer is much more relevant.

It seems like the original question was a classic example of the XY problem. "How to do X using Y?". You've answered the "How to do X in the best way?", but then the question was edited to "How to use Y?"...

Answer (score 10):

It's not as succinct as [Tim Yates's answer using findAll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518507/217324); but just for the record, you *can* use `collectEntries` to do this:

```
[ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 ].collectEntries { 
    it.value > 2 ? [(it.key) : it.value] : [:] }
```

which evaluates to

```
[c:3, d:4]
```

[Using "${it.key}" as done in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13518570/217324) is an error, the key will end up being an instance of the GStringImpl class, not a String.  The answer itself looks ok in the REPL but if you check what class it is, you can see it is wrong:

```
groovy:000> m = [ a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4 ]
===> [a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4]
groovy:000> m.collectEntries { ["${it.key}" : it.value ] }
===> [a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4]
groovy:000> _.keySet().each { println(it.class) }
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
===> [a, b, c, d]
```

Code trying to equate GroovyStrings to normal strings will evaluate to false even when the strings look identical, resulting in a hard-to-figure-out bug.

Comment: Since the original question is quite general, I believe that your answer is more correct than the accepted answer. With `findAll` you're just filtering the original items, which remain unmodified. With `collectEntries`, the resulting map can contain a different kind of items than the source collection, so `collectEntries` allow to perform in a single operation both filtering and transforming (mapping) the items.

Comment: By the way, it's also ok for the collectEntries closure to just return `[ it.key, it.value ]`. It has the same effect as `[ (it.key): it.value ]`.

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
[a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4].collectEntries {
    if (it.value > 2)
        ["${it.key}": it.value]
}
```

Comment: Throws a NPE as is.  You need an `else [:]`

Answer (score -1):

it works now after adding else. thanks

```
[a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4].collectEntries {
    if (it.value > 2){
        ["${it.key}": it.value]
    }else{
      [:]
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not solve the issue pointed to by Nathan Hughes, the keys will be instances of `GStringImpl` and not a regular String. To use variables as map keys, just surround them with braces: `[(it.key): it.value]`

Comment: Can also return [ it.key, it.value ], it gives the same results